# Ruby regexp for replace some sequence

Tags: ruby, regex

How I can convert string -

```
text = "test test1 \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n test2 \n"
```

to

```
test test1 \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n test2\n
```

I tried use next - `text.gsub(/\s\n/, '\n')`, but it added additional slash -

```
test test1\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n test2\\n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes, instead of single:

```
text.gsub(/\s\n/, "\n")
```

With single quotes, `\n` has the meaning of `\` and `n`, one after another. With double, it is interpreted as new line.

Comment: With this there will be no space after `test1`

Comment: @Abhi, I think he didn't want to have space there and it was just mistake on his part. You can see that the space after `test2` is expected to be removed. If he indeed wants to have the space, he should further clarify which spaces should be removed and which - not.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that either the space after `"test1"` is to be removed as well or the space after `"test2"` is not to be removed. @ndn assumed the former was intended. If the second interpretation applies, you could do the following:

```
r = /
    (?<=\n) # match \n in a positive lookbehind
    \s      # match a whitespace character
    (?=\n)  # match \n in a positive lookahead
    /x      # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

text.gsub(r,"")
    #=> "test test1 \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n test2 \n"
```

or:

```
text.gsub(/\n\s(?=\n)/, "\n")
```